# Eclipse errors when trying to run

Tags: android, eclipse

When i'm trying to run eclipse i'm getting this errors:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

and

```
DeviceMonitor] Sending Tracking request failed!
```

And when i'm trying to exit eclipse i'm gettin' this warning:

```
Problems occured while trying to save the state of workbench
```

I tried to delete the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/`-folder. Tried to create new workspace. Nothing changes. What do i need to do?

Comment: Try creating a new workspace and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Why is this tagged *android*?

Comment: I created new workspace problems didn't persisted. Tagged android becouse i'm working with android with eclipse.

Comment: Before it was ok. It started when i did chkdsk and when i was trying to run pc, the screen went black, then i did system restore. PC started working, but i've got this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your workspace has probably been corrupted.

Try running eclipse.exe -clean to fix it.

If that doenst work then create a new workspace and import your project under: File > Import > General > Existing Project into Workspace.

Comment: It goes ok, but when i'm tryin' to import existing project(s) i'm gettin'update installed JREs encountered a problem ant then project has no project.properties file and this many many times